# Running Python scripts from cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

I've installed python 3.7, but whenever I try and run a script in cmd, it says: `Requested Python Version (3.7) is not installed`.

Now, I start my scripts with `#!/usr/bin/env python3.7`, which just means that I don't have to write python3.7 in to cmd.

But, when I start my script with `#!/usr/bin/env python`, the script runs perfectly fine on cmd. What does this mean? Is it not running my script in Python3.7?

Comment: can you try doing `#!/usr/bin/env python --version` and tell me the output?

Comment: @ori6151 ```Python 3.7.4``` is the output.

Comment: Then where is the problem?

Comment: @ori6151 When I put ```#!/usr/bin/env python --version``` at the start of my script, and then try and run the script in cmd, the output is simply ```Python 3.7.4```, it doesn't run  my script?

Comment: If you try to run Python3.7 from the console by typing `python3.7` what happens?

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb ``` 'python3.7' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.``` But, when I simply type ```python``` in to cmd, it starts Python 3.7.4 interactively, with the ```>>>```.

Answer (score 1):

`#!/usr/bin/env xxx` looks for the first `xxx` to appear in `$PATH`.

You have python installed to the `python` path and likely nothing for `python3.7` which means that your script is running when you have it as `python` and not for `python3.7` because it doesn't know what to run when it can't find `python3.7` in `$PATH`. You could probably try `python3.7.4` since that is your specific version and it might work but it all depends on how it was installed and setup.

If you wanted to make `python3.7` work instead, you could look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496461/how-to-make-python3-7-default) and more information on this issue [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29608/why-is-it-better-to-use-usr-bin-env-name-instead-of-path-to-name-as-my).